# How much data / context needed to train custom NER Spacy model?

Tags: machine-learning, model, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to extract previous Job titles from a CV using spacy and named entity recognition.

I would like to train spacy to detect a custom named entity type : 'JOB'. For that I have around 800 job title names from https://www.careerbuilder.com/browse/titles/ that I can use as training data.

In my training data for spacy, do I need to integrate these job titles in sentences added to provide context or not?
In general in the CV the job title kinda stands on it's own and is not really part of a full sentence.

Also, if I need to provide coherent context for each of the 800 titles, it will be too time-consuming for what I'm trying to do, so maybe there are other solutions than NER?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, Named Entity Recognition relies on the context of words, otherwise the model would not be able to detect entities in previously unseen words. Consequently, the list of titles would not help you to train any model. You could rather run string matching to find any of those 800 titles in CV documents and you will even be guaranteed to find all of them - no unknown titles, though.

I you could find 800 (or less) real CVs and replace the Job names by those in your list (or others!), then you are all set to train a model capable of NER. This would be the way to go, I suppose. Just download as many freely available CVs from the web and see where this gets you. If it is not enough data, you can augment it, for example by exchanging the job titles in the data by some of the titles in your list.

Comment: Okay I might try that. I have a database of CV already available. However for each CV should I include the full text of the CV or just a few lines around the job titles?

Comment: Since your final goal is to automatically detect job titles in CV documents, you should train the model with the exact same task. Simply annotate the (few) job title entities in your training set documents. I would recommend you to use annotation software, e.g. [INCEpTION](https://inception-project.github.io/).

Comment: Okay, last question. If I do this based on an existing spacy model (like en_core_web_trf), do I have to annotate all the existing Named Entities too? I want my model to still be able to recognize dates/organizations and others too.

Comment: In that case, yes, you need to annotate all existing entities. Otherwise the model will unlearn to correctly recognize them. Imagine it would be irritated by seeing words that would normally form an entity, but are not labelled as such.